# How to export video file ? - livecode

Tags: livecode

I create player and I want to export video file form player to my folder.

Here my code:

```
 put the long id of control crd of card ID namecurrent of stack stackname into longIDofVdoName
 export longIDofImageName to file (specialFolderPath("desktop") & slash & "savejs/media/" & tControls[crd]["name"] &".mp4")
```

The file from export is not video file.

Comment: Since the player's fileName property points to the file it plays, you can just copy the file to the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Player controls only play videos that are stored externally to the stack, so there is nothing to export. The reference to the video is stored in the `fileName` property of the player. So if you want to create a copy of the video in another location, what you really need to do is to copy it from the current location in the file system to another location. The code would look like this:

```
put "binfile:" & the filename of player "myplayer" into tSourceURL
put "binfile:" & specialFolderPath("Desktop") & "/foldername/myvideo.mp4" \
   into tDestURL
put URL tSourceURL into URL tDestURL
```

If you want you can then delete the original file like this:

```
delete file (the filename of player "my player")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [EnhancedQT external](http://www.bluemangolearning.com/revolution/software/externals/eqt/) to export (part of) the movie. This allows you to export different formats and merge movie files and sound files. It isn't easy to use but it works.